# find and edit source code of installed python libraries in Google Colab on Windows

Tags: python, windows, google-colaboratory

I downloaded a library and need to make changes to the source code/source file. The library seems to be located at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages. Where can I find the files on Windows?

Comment: Open the Python interpreter, import the library, type the libraries name and press Enter. You will see the location.

Answer (score 0):

By default the install location is C:\Python39 - so it would be C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find out where Python is installed on Windows. Incase if you installed Python by downloading the application from its website, the application should be installed by default in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`

Once you opened the installation folder, head over to the `Lib\site-packages` directory and you can find the source code folders of installed packages. Hope that helps to solve your problem.